# Custom Dreamweaver "'Field' Cannot be null" error

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, validation

**Problem:**
I have a **Login Page**: [image: Login Page] If any of the following text field is not filled. It will **display this page**: [image: this page] Which is to be expected. However, I just wanted to know if there's anyway instead of redirecting that empty error page, it will redirect to this **error page** I made: [image: error page]

This is the code for the login page I made in Adobe Dreamweaver CS3:

```html
<?php require_once('Connections/sistemdaftar.php'); ?>
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . doubleval($theValue) . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}

// *** Redirect if username exists
$MM_flag="MM_insert";
if (isset($_POST[$MM_flag])) {
  $MM_dupKeyRedirect="daftarMuridFail.php";
  $loginUsername = $_POST['nokp'];
  $LoginRS__query = sprintf("SELECT nokp FROM pelajar WHERE nokp=%s", GetSQLValueString($loginUsername, "text"));
  mysql_select_db($database_sistemdaftar, $sistemdaftar);
  $LoginRS=mysql_query($LoginRS__query, $sistemdaftar) or die(mysql_error());
  $loginFoundUser = mysql_num_rows($LoginRS);

  //if there is a row in the database, the username was found - can not add the requested username
  if($loginFoundUser){
    $MM_qsChar = "?";
    //append the username to the redirect page
    if (substr_count($MM_dupKeyRedirect,"?") >=1) $MM_qsChar = "&";
    $MM_dupKeyRedirect = $MM_dupKeyRedirect . $MM_qsChar ."requsername=".$loginUsername;
    header ("Location: $MM_dupKeyRedirect");
    exit;
  }
}

$editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
  $editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}

if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "form1")) {
  $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO pelajar (nokp, nama, jantina, kaum, agama, kodKelas, kodJawatan, alamat) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['nokp'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['nama'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['RadioGroup1'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['kaum'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['agama'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['kelas'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['jawatan'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['alamat'], "text"));

  mysql_select_db($database_sistemdaftar, $sistemdaftar);
  $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $sistemdaftar) or die(mysql_error());

  $insertGoTo = "berjayaPelajarDaftar.php";
  if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
    $insertGoTo .= (strpos($insertGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
    $insertGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
  }
  header(sprintf("Location: %s", $insertGoTo));
}

if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "form1")) {
  $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO jawatan (kodJawatan, nokp) VALUES (%s, %s)",
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['jawatan'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['nokp'], "text"));

  mysql_select_db($database_sistemdaftar, $sistemdaftar);
  $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $sistemdaftar) or die(mysql_error());

  $insertGoTo = "berjayaPelajarDaftar.php";
  if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
    $insertGoTo .= (strpos($insertGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
    $insertGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
  }
  header(sprintf("Location: %s", $insertGoTo));
}

mysql_select_db($database_sistemdaftar, $sistemdaftar);
$query_Recordset1 = "SELECT * FROM jawatan,kelas,pelajar";
$Recordset1 = mysql_query($query_Recordset1, $sistemdaftar) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1);
$totalRows_Recordset1 = mysql_num_rows($Recordset1);
?><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<!-- DW6 -->
<head>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico" >
<!-- Copyright 2005 Macromedia, Inc. All rights reserved. -->
<title>Pendaftaran Rekod Pelajar</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mm_entertainment.css" type="text/css" />
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body,td,th {
 color: #333333;
}
.style1 {color: #435896}
.style3 {color: #89b9c5}
body {
 background-image: url(images/Background.png);
}
.style15 {
 color: #234A56;
 font-family: "Century Gothic";
}
.style10 {color: #234A56}
.style13 { font-family: "Century Gothic";
 font-size: 24px;
 font-style: italic;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #234A56;
}
.style7 {color: #F0F0F0}
.style9 {font-family: "Century Gothic"}
-->
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function MM_popupMsg(msg) { //v1.0
  alert(msg);
}
function MM_goToURL() { //v3.0
  var i, args=MM_goToURL.arguments; document.MM_returnValue = false;
  for (i=0; i<(args.length-1); i+=2) eval(args[i]+".location='"+args[i+1]+"'");
}
//-->
</script>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#39626e" onerror="MM_goToURL('parent','daftarMuridOnError.php');return document.MM_returnValue">
<span class="style1"></span>
<table width="130%" height="348" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr bgcolor="02021e">
    <td height="139" nowrap="nowrap" bgcolor="#39626e">&nbsp;
      <div align="center"></div>
    <div align="center"></div></td>
    <td height="139" colspan="2" nowrap="nowrap" bgcolor="#39626e"><div align="center"><img src="images/Head2.png" alt="" width="733" height="146" /></div></td>
    <td height="139" nowrap="nowrap" bgcolor="#39626e">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
     <td width="69" rowspan="4" valign="top" bgcolor="89b9c5">&nbsp;</td>
     <td height="22" colspan="2" valign="top" bgcolor="89b9c5">&nbsp;</td>
     <td width="90" rowspan="4" bgcolor="89b9c5">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
     <td height="48" colspan="2" valign="top" bgcolor="89b9c5"><form id="form1" name="form1" method="POST" action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>">
       <table width="504" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#89B9C5">
         <tr>
           <td colspan="5" bgcolor="#89B9C5" class="subHeader style3"><h2 align="center"><span class="style13"><U>Pendaftaran Rekod Pelajar</U></span></h2></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td colspan="5" bgcolor="#89B9C5" class="subHeader style3"><div align="center"></div></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td width="94" align="right" valign="baseline" nowrap="nowrap" bgcolor="#89B9C5"><span class="style9">Nokp:</span></td>
           <td colspan="2" valign="baseline" bgcolor="#89B9C5"><input name="nokp" type="text" value="" size="44" maxlength="12" /></td>
           <td width="31" bgcolor="#89B9C5" class="subHeader style7"><label><img src="images/info.png" width="25" height="25" align="top" onclick="MM_popupMsg('Kod Pengenalan Pelajar yang hendak direkod perlu diisi di medan ini.\r*Tidak Boleh Ditinggal Kosong\r*Tidak Boleh melibihi 12 angka')" /></label></td>
           <td width="53" rowspan="3" bgcolor="#89B9C5" class="subHeader style7">&nbsp;</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td align="right" valign="baseline" nowrap="nowrap" bgcolor="#89B9C5"><span class="style9">Nama:</span></td>
           <td colspan="2" valign="baseline" bgcolor="#89B9C5"><input name="nama" type="text" value="" size="44" maxlength="100" /></td>
           <td width="31" bgcolor="#89B9C5" class="subHeader style7"><img src="images/info.png" alt="" width="25" height="25" align="top" onclick="MM_popupMsg('Nama Pelajar yang hendak direkod perlu diisi di medan ini.\r*Tidak Boleh Ditinggal Kosong\r')" /></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td align="right" valign="baseline" nowrap="nowrap" bgcolor="#89B9C5"><span class="style9">Jantina:</span></td>
           <td colspan="2" valign="baseline" bgcolor="#89B9C5"><table width="262">
               <tr>
                 <td width="105"><span class="style15">
                   <label>
                   <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="Lelaki" id="RadioGroup1_0" />
                     Lelaki</label>
                 </span></td>
                 <td><span class="style15">
                   <label>
                   <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="Perempuan" id="RadioGroup1_1" />
                     Perempuan</label>
                 </span></td>
               </tr>
             </table>
               <label></label></td>
           <td width="31" bgcolor="#89B9C5" class="subHeader style7"><img src="images/info.png" alt="" width="25" height="25" align="top" onclick="MM_popupMsg('*Jantina pelajar perlu dipilih antara 2 pilihan ini.\r*Tidak ditinggal kosong\r')" /></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td align="right" valign="baseline" nowrap="nowrap" bgcolor="#89B9C5"><span class="style9">Kaum:</span></td>
           <td colspan="2" valign="baseline" bgcolor="#89B9C5"><label>
             <select name="kaum" id="kaum">
               <option>SILA PILIH</option>
               <option value="Melayu">Melayu</option>
               <option value="Cina">Cina</option>
               <option value="India">India</option>
               <option value="Lain-Lain">Lain-Lain</option>
             </select>
             <span class="subHeader style7"><img src="images/info.png" alt="" width="25" height="25" align="top" onclick="MM_popupMsg('*Kaum pelajar perlu dipilih di sini\r*Tidak ditinggal kosong')" /></span><br />
           </label></td>
           <td colspan="2" bgcolor="#89B9C5" class="subHeader style7">&nbsp;</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td align="right" valign="baseline" nowrap="nowrap" bgcolor="#89B9C5"><span class="style9">Agama:</span></td>
           <td colspan="2" valign="baseline" bgcolor="#89B9C5"><label>
             <select name="agama" id="agama">
               <option>SILA PILIH</option>
               <option value="Islam">Islam</option>
               <option value="Buddha">Buddha</option>
               <option value="Hindu">Hindu</option>
               <option value="Kristian">Kristian</option>
               <option value="Lain-Lain">Lain-Lain</option>
             </select>
             <span class="subHeader style7"><img src="images/info.png" alt="" width="25" height="25" align="top" onclick="MM_popupMsg('*Agama pelajar perlu dipilih di sini\r*Tidak ditinggal kosong\r')" /></span></label></td>
           <td colspan="2" bgcolor="#89B9C5" class="subHeader style7">&nbsp;</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td align="right" valign="baseline" nowrap="nowrap" bgcolor="#89B9C5"><span class="style9">Kelas:</span></td>
           <td colspan="2" valign="baseline" bgcolor="#89B9C5"><label>
             <select name="kelas" id="kelas">
               <option value="-" selected="selected">SILA PILIH</option>
               <option value="S41">4Sains1</option>
               <option value="S42">4Sains2</option>
               <option value="S43">4SainsTeknologi</option>
               <option value="P41">4Perakaunan1</option>
               <option value="P42">4Perakaunan2</option>
               <option value="A41">4Sastera1</option>
               <option value="A42">4Sastera2</option>
               <option value="A43">4Sastera3</option>
               <option value="A44">4Sastera4</option>
               <option value="A45">4Sastera5</option>
               <option value="A46">4Sastera6</option>
               <option value="A47">4Sastera7</option>
               <option value="A48">4Sastera8</option>
             </select>
             <span class="subHeader style7"><img src="images/info.png" alt="" width="25" height="25" align="top" onclick="MM_popupMsg('*Kelas pelajar perlu dipilih di sini\r*Tidak ditinggal kosong\r')" /></span></label></td>
           <td colspan="2" rowspan="3" bgcolor="#89B9C5" class="subHeader style7">&nbsp;</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td align="right" valign="baseline" nowrap="nowrap" bgcolor="#89B9C5"><span class="style9">Jawatan:</span></td>
           <td colspan="2" valign="baseline" bgcolor="#89B9C5"><label>
             <select name="jawatan" id="jawatan">
               <option value="J07" selected="selected">SILA PILIH</option>
               <option value="J00">Pengerusi</option>
               <option value="J01">Naib Pengerusi</option>
               <option value="J02">Bendahari</option>
               <option value="J03">Naib Bendahari</option>
               <option value="J04">Setiausaha</option>
               <option value="J05">Naib Setiausaha</option>
               <option value="J06">Ahli Jawatan Kuasa (AJK)</option>
               <option value="J07">Ahli Biasa</option>
             </select>
             <span class="subHeader style7"><img src="images/info.png" alt="" width="25" height="25" align="top" onclick="MM_popupMsg('*Jawatan pelajar perlu dipilih di sini\r*Tidak ditinggal kosong\r')" /></span></label></td>
          </tr>
         <tr>
           <td align="right" valign="baseline" nowrap="nowrap" bgcolor="#89B9C5"><span class="style9">Alamat:</span></td>
           <td width="228" valign="baseline" bgcolor="#89B9C5"><label>
             <input type="text" name="alamat" id="alamat" />
             <span class="subHeader style7"><img src="images/info.png" alt="" width="25" height="25" align="top" onclick="MM_popupMsg('*alamat pelajar perlu dipilih di sini\r*Boleh ditinggal kosong')" /></span></label></td>
           <td width="78" valign="baseline" bgcolor="#89B9C5">&nbsp;</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td colspan="5" bgcolor="#89B9C5" class="subHeader style7 style9"><div align="center" class="style10">Notis : Medan Alamat Tidak Wajib Diisi</div></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td colspan="5" bgcolor="#89B9C5" class="subHeader style7"><div align="center">
               <label>
               <input height="34" width="144" type="image" name="submit2" id="submit2" src="images/DaftarMuridButton.png" />
               </label>
           </div></td>
         </tr>
       </table>
          <input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="form1" />
     </form>
     </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="48" colspan="2" valign="top" bgcolor="89b9c5"><span class="style3"><br />
 </span>
     <table width="504" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
          <td class="subHeader style3">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="391" height="22" bgcolor="89b9c5">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="389" bgcolor="89b9c5">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="46" colspan="4" valign="top" bgcolor="#234A56">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br />
</body>
</html>
<?php
mysql_free_result($Recordset1);
?>
```

For references:

This is the Screenshot of the login page:

[Login Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kf0qW.png)

This is the Screenshot the Default Error Page:

[Error Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRuFK.png)

This is the Screenshot of the error page I made:

['My' Error Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4yUd.png)

Comment: Please note that the `mysql_*` functions have been **deprecated since 2013** (in PHP 5.5), and are **removed as of PHP 7** (released in 2015). This is because they have **serious** security vulnerabilities. **DO NOT USE THEM**. Please consider switching to either [**MySQLi**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead, ensuring that you also use [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to prevent [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) :)

Comment: And for that matter, DreamWeaver CS3 was superseded in **2008** by CS4. There have been 10 new major release versions since CS3! You really should upgrade that as well...

Comment: The reason why I'm using a outdated PHP is because my school supplied me with a copy of an old Adobe Dreamweaver CS3. This is actually for a highschool assignment. The page's security vulnerabilities is not my priority. However, I will sure take you advice on using PHP 7 on future website developments :)

Comment: You Can Check First if($_POST['nokp']) if it is NULL then you can redirect your error page.

Comment: @bhavya-sanchaniya Can you elaborate? My web scripting skills still count as rookie.

Comment: yes, You can check your code where the **insert** SQL statement was executed before you can check the $_POST['nokp'] filed value is null then redirect your page otherwise it will not null then execute the SQL insert statement.

Comment: I found the answer, Thanks to all the kind people who have helped. For anyone from the future who wants to do the same. Use this code:<?php
 if(empty($_POST['nokp'])){

 header ("Location: daftarAdminOnError.php");
 }
?>

Comment: @GamekidXZ Okay Great.. Solution .. I hope my advice help too u And sorry for my english ..  :p

Comment: @bhavya-sanchaniya Your advice IS the solution. ._.Thank you.